# migration from SVN to GIT modifcation shell script

Tags: git, shell, svn

I am modifying my shell script from svn to Git
at the beginning they defined :

BRANCHES=trunk

do I want to change it to

BRANCHES=$(git symbolic-ref HEAD | sed -e 's,.*/(.*),\1,')

or

BRANCHES=master

2nd question please, they remove the tag this way

vn delete Root SVN/tags/version

to
git tag -d Root GIT/tags/version

Thank you so much

Comment: Hi and welcome to you. What's the second question here exactly?

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. Are you getting errors? What happens when you run your script?

Comment: @RomainValeri   the script is correct? thnqs

Comment: @Gino Mempin  nooo ,just i want to know if my script and correct: is that i can edit trunk by master or by $(git symbolic-ref HEAD | sed -e 's,./(.),\1,')

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Stackoverflow. Symbolic-ref will resolve to a symbolic reference if you have used a branch with the last `git checkout`, it will fail if you have used a tag or a commitid, so you should be careful using it in a script.

Without knowing the intention of `BRANCHES`, using `master` will probably be a safer choice.

EDIT:

Tags `Root` and `GIT/tags/version` will be removed, if they exists in the git-repo, otherwise it will fail. I find it odd, I would have exported `SVN/tags/version` to `version`, but, without knowing how tags have been exported from SVN to GIT it's hard to say if it's correct or not.

Comment: thank you so much Joran ,for the second question I just want to replace the svn command with a GIT command.for the first question you're right I did : branches=master